# could not use packages 'from pymilvus' in colab Milvus version 2.3.1

Tags: google-colaboratory

Just run some codes to try Milvus-lite with python in colab, but got confused about the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-22b8ee548332> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 get_ipython().system('python3 -m pip install milvus==2.3.1')
      2 from milvus import default_server
----> 3 from pymilvus import utility
      4 #from pymilvus import connections, utility
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymilvus'
```

The original python codes as following:

```
!python3 -m pip install milvus==2.3.1
from milvus import default_server
from pymilvus import utility
```

I can use the default_server but can not use the utility from pymilvus.As I tested the packages from Milvus can work such as

```
default_server.start()
```

But I tried several ways to use pymilvus without any results. Do I missing some cmd there? The version of Python on colab is 3.10.12?